# why after adding mainaxis and crossaxis to center my widget is not coming to center from any direction

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment, center

This is my  code now I want to align my Text widget to the center of the screen but it is not taking any of the properties neither the cross axis alignment nor the main axis alignment, if i am wrapping Text widget with center then it is coming horizontally axis but still not vertically, i tried with container widget also

```
Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text("Please add some notes"),
                      ],
                    );
```

Here below is my full code

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                future:ref.orderBy('Time',descending: true).get(),
                builder: (context,snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.hasData&&snapshot.data?.docs.length!=0){
                    return ListView.builder(
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 2, 2, 2),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context,index){
                          Map data= snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map;
                          DateTime mynote_time=data['Time'].toDate();
                          String formattedTime =
                          DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(mynote_time);
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Card(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 1, 3, 1),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "${data['title']}",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 1, 3, 1),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "${data['description']}",
                                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                      child: Text(
                                          formattedTime
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                borderOnForeground: true,
                                shadowColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                                color: Colors.grey[100],
                                elevation: 10,
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                    );
                  }
                  else if(snapshot.data?.docs.length==0){
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(child: Text("Please add some notes")),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                  else return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SpinKitPumpingHeart(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        size: 150,
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                      ),
                      Text("Please wait.....")
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[100],
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Write_Note()));
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            size: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
    );
```

In both the conditions none of them coming to the center, I am not getting why so happening

Answer (score 0):

In order for vertical and horizontal levels to work, it must have height and width.

```
Container(
  height: 600,
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
           children: [
             Text("Please add some notes"),
           ],
       ),
);
```